# Sas Pie charts CrossHatched pattern

Tags: charts, sas, pie-chart, gchart

How do I add CrossHatched pattern to a pie chart in SaS (as simple as possible). I'm trying to read up on the pattern statement but I don't know how to just add the crosshatched pattern to my existing pie chart. So far the program looks like this.

```
proc gchart data=orion.personl;
   pie JobCode / sumvar = salary type=mean explode="TA3";
   where JobCode in ('TA1', 'TA2', 'TA3');
run;
```

and I just need to add the crosshatched pattern to it. Please help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would specifying the fill pattern work:

```
proc gchart data=orion.personl;
   pie JobCode / sumvar = salary type=mean explode="TA3" fill=x;
   where JobCode in ('TA1', 'TA2', 'TA3');
run;
```

Where X rotates a single hatch pattern through the list of colors defined in the current style.